# Specifying only a single index of a 1D array in a data file

Tags: minizinc

Consider the following toy model, call it `foo.mzn`:

```
int: n = 2;
array[1..n] of var 0..2: vert;

constraint vert[1] != vert[2];

solve satisfy;
```

[The documentation (Listing 2.2.3)](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.2.0/en/modelling2.html#fig-prod-planning-data) shows an example where the data file specifies the entire array. That is, you could do:

```
./minizinc -D "vert=[0,1]" foo.mzn
```

However, what if I only want to specify one index of the array? It feels reasonable to be able to do:

```
./minizinc -D "vert[1]=0" foo.mzn
```

but this results in

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected =, expecting ':'
```

Is it possible to specify only a single index of an array in a data file? An alternative is to do away without an array, but perhaps this is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to define the second element as an unknown/unassigned value (`_`), e.g.

```
./minizinc -D "vert[0,_]" foo.mzn
```

This yields two solutions:

```
vert: [0, 1]
vert: [0, 2]
```